# Can i publish a paper on a concept for which I filed a patent recently and got the application number

Tags: patentability

I have recently filed an Indian patent and got my application number.. Is it ok for me to publish a research on the same now, by mentioning application number in my publication?

Answer (score 2):

Anything published after the filing of an application can not be used against that application.

I don't see a reason to include the patent number in the paper, you certainly don't have to, but if you want, you could.

Comment: Indeed, some papers might use the phrase "patent pending".

Answer (score 0):

In some countries you might have to wait for an authorisation from the army/ministry of defence to divulge it.